# How to validate a Response with numbers in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I got the following response - Pre-Note added with PIN (1368)

The PIN number will not be the same always, so, how can I write a re-runnable test to validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.match(/<text>Pre-Note added with PIN ([\d]{4})<\/text>/);
```

you can use chai match method that uses regex , here this rehex will validate the pin is 4digit number

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: I have tried the code but still getting errors, below is the response I got:

<text>Pre-Note added with PIN 1379</text>

I have written in this format

pm.test("60005-02 : Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("<text>Pre-Note added with PIN [\d]{4}</text>");
});

Please let me know if this correct?

Comment: ypu have to use match not include , use the code as it is

Comment: I have used the code as it is, getting this error Body matches string | ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: repalce a with (pm.response.text())

Comment: please accept the answer by clickign the tick sign if it helped